# Swift how to assign a string to a UITextField?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

```
@IBOutlet weak var resultProcessed: UITextField!
var str:String = "Mike is here"
resultProcessed = str
```

gives error: Cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'UITestField!'

Comment: This is a very basic question. You shall refer to the doc https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html

Comment: yes agree. Thank you for reference also :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
resultProcessed.text = str
```

You need to assign it to the `text` property.

Comment: thank you, rookie or beginner problem :) I was trying: as! String