# [Swift]How to assign a string to a UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift

I can build and it succeeds, but when i push button it breaks and i dont know why.
I read this↓ and I'm sure that i add 「.text」 but didnt work.
[Swift how to assign a string to a UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093423/swift-how-to-assign-a-string-to-a-uitextfield)
Please tell me why.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
@IBAction func tapHandler(sender: AnyObject) {
    myTextField.text = "success"
}
```

Comment: Did you get any crash error while click the button?

Comment: when i click the button, the simulator immediately crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

1) Check your Outlet textfield connection 
2) Then add button action for your button

```
 @IBAction func tapHandler(sender: UIButton) {
    myTextField.text = "success"
}
```

Comment: it worked!  i may have done it in reverse order or they werent connected.
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to assign Text to the Field. Are you Sure that the Textfield, is set to the variable? And are you sure that the function is called? When should the method get called which event is connected to the Method, it think the method never get called. You can try it with the debugger or easier with an e.g. `println("called")`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@IBAction func tapHandler(sender: UIButton) {
    myTextField.text = "success"
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.